# "Deployment Options" for web app disabled in Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

When I create a **web app for containers**, then the deployment options are disabled in the Azure portal. The option is enabled if I create a regular web app and another type of resources. For web app for containers, the options was working fine till a few days back and I have no idea what triggered it to become disabled. My subscription is active and clearing browser cache, switching browsers, working with different container images, deleting and recreating resource groups, and login/logout do not help. Any suggestions?

[image: Azure portal message for deployment option where creating a web app for containers]

Comment: What kind of account are you using? Free or Pay-as-you-go?

Comment: It's a pay-as-you-go account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The customer support team resolved the problem and cited "platform issue" as the cause of the problem. Now deployment options for container web apps is enabled and working again.

Answer (score 3):

The "Enable Deployment Options within Web App for Containers in the portal" feature was requested on [feedback.azure.com](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/32613268--linux-enable-deployment-options-within-web-app) and declined.

Q. Currently "Deployment Options" is only available for Web App for Windows/Linux. It would be nice if this was enabled for Web App for Containers...so I lost the simple ability to deploy from BitBucket.

A. The App Service team responded: We are declining this request since we actually discourage customers to deploy this way and recommend deployment with Container Push. **That being said, there is nothing stopping you from configuring this through CLI.**

To do this from the CLI, you could use this command:

```
az webapp deployment source config -n appname -g resourcegroupname --repo-url <gitrepo url> --branch <branch>
```

See [Manage Web App for Containers using Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-cli#set-up-git-deployments-for-your-web-app) for more details.

Comment: Tried to deploy via powershell as well. It continues to fail saying that the resource is in a failed state even for a new resource. This above comment from azure feedback team is quite confusing as the Deployment Options was working fine for this account till end of last week.

Comment: Worth noting that if you use one of the pre-fabbed runtimes, you can use deployment options. But once you move to custom containers you can't.

Comment: What do the logs say? (Monitoring-diagnostic logs-enable, then advanced tools-go-download logs as zip).

Answer (score 1):

I have created **Azure Web App which OS is Docker** and reproduced your issue.

From the screenshot , we can find the issue may caused by **App Service Plan**. I have tried to use all tiers of plan, including **Isolated**, but the issue is still existing. Also, for regular web app, not have the issue.

I find some updates on [Azure App Service](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/05/13/april-2018-app-service-update/). I am not sure if the issue was caused by the updates, I recommend you to contact [**App Service Support Team**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/hh361695) for help.

Comment: I have opened a case with their technical support. I hope they provide some resolution soon.